# Отсутствие панелей в Sublime Text 3 после установки

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text

Установил *Sublime Text 3* на Ubuntu, но на нем нет панелей (меню). Ставил на Windows - там есть все сразу.

Как это можно исправить? (*Package Control* поставил и перегружал).

Comment: Пожалуйста, распишите подробнее Ваше решение (например, со скриншотами) и отметьте его как ответ (зеленая галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блин ступил!
(Для новый пользователей Ubuntu подскажу)
Меню этого редактора доступно на верхней панели окна (а не программы). Смотрите внимательней. 
(в windows панелька находится в окошке даже если не на все окно развернуто).

Чтобы понять о чем я пишу просто сделайте активным sublime и нажмите клавишу "Alt" и вы увидите что будет менятся на мониторе. То что меняется и есть меню)))